# how to clean database before running the each spec file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails, database-cleaner

I want to clear my test database before running the each spec files.

I am already using rspec with factory girl.

Thanks,
Hare

Comment: Are you using `database_cleaner` gem?

Comment: Yes, I am using it. But not sure how to write for each file.

Answer (score 8):

Add to `RSpec.configure` block in your `spec_helper.rb`

```
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
```

Must work

Comment: Actually in my spec/controllers fold has many controllers, i want clean my database before running each controllers.

Comment: One should clean their database before executing each test. It's necessary to ensure that the test executed previously did not affect the testing environment prepared for the current test e.g. there was not any garbage in your test database.

Comment: Why do you need to set the strategy `before :each`? Isn't `before :suite` sufficient?

Comment: To clean your database after each test so the next test could use clean database without garbage from the previous test. The idea is you need to run every single test on a clean setup

Answer (score 3):

In your spec_helper.rb,
inside the RSpec.configure block

```
RSpec.configure do |config|

  # ...

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:all) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:all) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

  # ...
end
```

before(:all) and after(:all) runs for every spec file and not before and after the whole suite. So, for every spec file you will be able to clear database using any of the three strategies :transaction, :truncation, :deletion

Comment: ? This looks just like @VAD's answer from Jan 28, 2017.

Comment: VAD's answer will clean database for every single test case, mine does it for every single spec file(which was the actual question). the difference is :all instead of :each

Answer (score 0):

This is what I typically do for `DatabaseCleaner`

```
# Database Cleaner
config.before(:suite) do
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
end
config.before(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.start
end
config.after(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
end
```

That will make sure you have a clean database for each test.

Checkout [a related, albeit old, article by Avdi](http://www.virtuouscode.com/2012/08/31/configuring-database_cleaner-with-rails-rspec-capybara-and-selenium/) for more info.